# Word which is not in line with the others

Tags: beamer, tikz-arrows

How I can fixed the "word" which is not in line with the remaining ones in the following code?

```
\documentclass[10pt,xcolor={dvipsnames,table}]{beamer}

\mode<article> % only for the article version
{
  \usepackage{fullpage}
  \usepackage{hyperref}
}


\mode<presentation>
{
  %\setbeamertemplate{background canvas}[vertical shading][bottom=red!10,top=blue!10]
  \setbeamercovered{transparent}
  \usefonttheme{serif}
  \usecolortheme{crane}
}

\usepackage{tikz}

\setbeamercovered{dynamic}

\setbeamertemplate{items}[circle]


\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
Consider the equation
\begin{equation*}
A = B \hspace*{0.5cm} \tikz[baseline,remember picture]{
\node[fill=blue!20,opacity=.6,anchor=base,align=center,font=\color{blue}\tiny] (t1) {My Theorem (...)};
}
\end{equation*}
This \tikz[remember picture, baseline=-.5ex] \node (n1) {word}; is a little misplaced.
\begin{tikzpicture}[overlay,remember picture]
    \draw<1->[->,blue,opacity=.6] (n1) -- (t1);
\end{tikzpicture} 

\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Comment: For your previous question, you might want to read up on [How do you accept an answer?](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1852)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With `baseline=-.5ex` you shift the baseline of the tikzpicture. This will shift the word inside the node as well.

As said before: have a look at the `tikzmark` library or the `hf-tikz` package instead of manually playing around with baselines and alignments. Then you won't run into problems like this.

```
\documentclass[10pt,xcolor={dvipsnames,table}]{beamer}

\mode<article> % only for the article version
{
  \usepackage{fullpage}
  \usepackage{hyperref}
}


\mode<presentation>
{
  %\setbeamertemplate{background canvas}[vertical shading][bottom=red!10,top=blue!10]
  \setbeamercovered{transparent}
  \usefonttheme{serif}
  \usecolortheme{crane}
}

\usepackage{tikz}

\setbeamercovered{dynamic}

\setbeamertemplate{items}[circle]

\usetikzlibrary{tikzmark}


\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
Consider the equation
\begin{equation*}
A = B \hspace*{0.5cm} \tikz[baseline,remember picture]{
\node[fill=blue!20,opacity=.6,anchor=base,align=center,font=\color{blue}\tiny] (t1) {My Theorem (...)};
}
\end{equation*}
This  \tikzmarknode{n1}{word} is a little misplaced.
\begin{tikzpicture}[overlay,remember picture]
    \draw<1->[->,blue,opacity=.6] (n1.north) -- (t1);
\end{tikzpicture} 

\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]